# How to restore element's original height with YUI3?

Tags: css, styles, yui3

I have an HTML element with a class that sets its height:

```
.myelem {
  height: 100px;
}
```

I change the element's height programmatically based on some conditions with something like:

```
Y.one('.myelem').setStyle('height', elem_height + "px");
```

At some point I would like to restore its height to the original value set by the `.myelem` class. Is there a way to do that with YUI3? Adding/removing class does not seem to work if the element has the height set with `setStyle()`.

I know I could save the original height in some variable, but that is unhandy to me since the element's class changes based on various conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Finally found this: setting the style to `null` restores its value to the one provided by the element's class. What I was looking for is simply:

```
Y.one('.myelem').setStyle('height', null);
```